# Do buttons on a jQuery UI Dialog have to be debounced?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, google-apps-script

I have been trying to use some jQuery UI dialogs in an app that I originally wrote in App Maker and I would like to have it as a regular web app.  But I've been having some problems with events happening more often than expected.

This code is part of a much bigger app because I find it helpful to solve problems by reducing the amount of stuff I have to deal with.  As the code enters the html page it goes and reads events on a certain calendar and displays them along with buttons that allow the user to edit and save each event description and also delete events.  In this case, I've also added some extra Sav and Edt buttons that do the same thing except that they don't use a dialog. It looks like the following image.

[image]

When you push the lower left Edit button you'll get a dialog that looks like this:

[image]

What happens is that if you push the Edit Button under an event description a dialog launches with that events description in a textarea.  If you push the Save button on the dialog then it's supposed to save that even description back to that event description on the calendar and then display the events again. But if you were push the edit button and then the save button seven times below is the console output:

For every openEventDescriptionEditDialog: idS=05 there should be one saveEventDescription: idS=05 and one userCodeAppPanel:6 dispEvents().  Sometimes the log indicates the number of dispEvents with the number out to the left.  They occur all at one time because they are on a .withSuccessHandler callback.  But as you can see that the first time you get just one and the second time you get two , third time 3, fourth time 5, fifth time 5 and so on.

```
/*
Unrecognized feature: 'vibrate'.
userCodeAppPanel:2 Unrecognized feature: 'vibrate'.
userCodeAppPanel:46 My code
userCodeAppPanel:6 dispEvents()
1995166154-warden_bin_i18n_warden.js:56 Net state changed from IDLE to BUSY
1995166154-warden_bin_i18n_warden.js:194 Co {message: "There was an error during the transport or process…this request. Error code = 10, Path = /wardeninit", name: "TransportError", stack: "TransportError: There was an error during the tran…/js/1995166154-warden_bin_i18n_warden.js:178:252)"}
1995166154-warden_bin_i18n_warden.js:56 Net state changed from BUSY to IDLE
userCodeAppPanel:15 openEventDescriptionEditDialog: idS=05 , text=Remove the if alreadySent routine.
userCodeAppPanel:21 n.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, timeStamp: 26307.999999999993, jQuery112407953633868134593: true, …}
userCodeAppPanel:38 saveEventDescription: idS=05 , text=First Time
1995166154-warden_bin_i18n_warden.js:56 Net state changed from IDLE to BUSY
1995166154-warden_bin_i18n_warden.js:56 Net state changed from BUSY to IDLE
userCodeAppPanel:6 dispEvents()
1995166154-warden_bin_i18n_warden.js:56 Net state changed from IDLE to BUSY
1995166154-warden_bin_i18n_warden.js:56 Net state changed from BUSY to IDLE
userCodeAppPanel:15 openEventDescriptionEditDialog: idS=05 , text=First Time
userCodeAppPanel:21 n.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, timeStamp: 38723.69999999955, jQuery112407953633868134593: true, …}
userCodeAppPanel:38 saveEventDescription: idS=05 , text=Second Time
userCodeAppPanel:21 n.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, timeStamp: 38723.69999999955, jQuery112407953633868134593: true, …}
userCodeAppPanel:38 saveEventDescription: idS=05 , text=Second Time
1995166154-warden_bin_i18n_warden.js:56 Net state changed from IDLE to BUSY
2userCodeAppPanel:6 dispEvents()
1995166154-warden_bin_i18n_warden.js:56 Net state changed from BUSY to IDLE
userCodeAppPanel:15 openEventDescriptionEditDialog: idS=05 , text=Second Time
userCodeAppPanel:21 n.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, timeStamp: 50924.50000000008, jQuery112407953633868134593: true, …}
userCodeAppPanel:38 saveEventDescription: idS=05 , text=Third time
userCodeAppPanel:21 n.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, timeStamp: 50924.50000000008, jQuery112407953633868134593: true, …}
userCodeAppPanel:38 saveEventDescription: idS=05 , text=Third time
userCodeAppPanel:21 n.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, timeStamp: 50924.50000000008, jQuery112407953633868134593: true, …}
userCodeAppPanel:38 saveEventDescription: idS=05 , text=Third time
1995166154-warden_bin_i18n_warden.js:56 Net state changed from IDLE to BUSY
3userCodeAppPanel:6 dispEvents()
1995166154-warden_bin_i18n_warden.js:56 Net state changed from BUSY to IDLE
userCodeAppPanel:15 openEventDescriptionEditDialog: idS=05 , text=Third time
userCodeAppPanel:21 n.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, timeStamp: 63643.79999999983, jQuery112407953633868134593: true, …}
userCodeAppPanel:38 saveEventDescription: idS=05 , text=Fourth Time
userCodeAppPanel:21 n.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, timeStamp: 63643.79999999983, jQuery112407953633868134593: true, …}
userCodeAppPanel:38 saveEventDescription: idS=05 , text=Fourth Time
userCodeAppPanel:21 n.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, timeStamp: 63643.79999999983, jQuery112407953633868134593: true, …}
userCodeAppPanel:38 saveEventDescription: idS=05 , text=Fourth Time
userCodeAppPanel:21 n.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, timeStamp: 63643.79999999983, jQuery112407953633868134593: true, …}
userCodeAppPanel:38 saveEventDescription: idS=05 , text=Fourth Time
1995166154-warden_bin_i18n_warden.js:56 Net state changed from IDLE to BUSY
4userCodeAppPanel:6 dispEvents()
1995166154-warden_bin_i18n_warden.js:56 Net state changed from BUSY to IDLE
userCodeAppPanel:15 openEventDescriptionEditDialog: idS=05 , text=Fourth Time
userCodeAppPanel:21 n.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, timeStamp: 85540.60000000027, jQuery112407953633868134593: true, …}
userCodeAppPanel:38 saveEventDescription: idS=05 , text=Fifth Time
userCodeAppPanel:21 n.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, timeStamp: 85540.60000000027, jQuery112407953633868134593: true, …}
userCodeAppPanel:38 saveEventDescription: idS=05 , text=Fifth Time
userCodeAppPanel:21 n.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, timeStamp: 85540.60000000027, jQuery112407953633868134593: true, …}
userCodeAppPanel:38 saveEventDescription: idS=05 , text=Fifth Time
userCodeAppPanel:21 n.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, timeStamp: 85540.60000000027, jQuery112407953633868134593: true, …}
userCodeAppPanel:38 saveEventDescription: idS=05 , text=Fifth Time
userCodeAppPanel:21 n.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, timeStamp: 85540.60000000027, jQuery112407953633868134593: true, …}
userCodeAppPanel:38 saveEventDescription: idS=05 , text=Fifth Time
1995166154-warden_bin_i18n_warden.js:56 Net state changed from IDLE to BUSY
5userCodeAppPanel:6 dispEvents()
1995166154-warden_bin_i18n_warden.js:56 Net state changed from BUSY to IDLE
userCodeAppPanel:15 openEventDescriptionEditDialog: idS=05 , text=Fifth Time
userCodeAppPanel:21 n.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, timeStamp: 100964.39999999985, jQuery112407953633868134593: true, …}
userCodeAppPanel:38 saveEventDescription: idS=05 , text=Sixth Time
userCodeAppPanel:21 n.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, timeStamp: 100964.39999999985, jQuery112407953633868134593: true, …}
userCodeAppPanel:38 saveEventDescription: idS=05 , text=Sixth Time
userCodeAppPanel:21 n.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, timeStamp: 100964.39999999985, jQuery112407953633868134593: true, …}
userCodeAppPanel:38 saveEventDescription: idS=05 , text=Sixth Time
userCodeAppPanel:21 n.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, timeStamp: 100964.39999999985, jQuery112407953633868134593: true, …}
userCodeAppPanel:38 saveEventDescription: idS=05 , text=Sixth Time
userCodeAppPanel:21 n.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, timeStamp: 100964.39999999985, jQuery112407953633868134593: true, …}
userCodeAppPanel:38 saveEventDescription: idS=05 , text=Sixth Time
userCodeAppPanel:21 n.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, timeStamp: 100964.39999999985, jQuery112407953633868134593: true, …}
userCodeAppPanel:38 saveEventDescription: idS=05 , text=Sixth Time
1995166154-warden_bin_i18n_warden.js:56 Net state changed from IDLE to BUSY
5userCodeAppPanel:6 dispEvents()
1995166154-warden_bin_i18n_warden.js:56 Net state changed from BUSY to IDLE
userCodeAppPanel:6 dispEvents()
1995166154-warden_bin_i18n_warden.js:56 Net state changed from IDLE to BUSY
1995166154-warden_bin_i18n_warden.js:56 Net state changed from BUSY to IDLE
userCodeAppPanel:15 openEventDescriptionEditDialog: idS=05 , text=Sixth Time
userCodeAppPanel:21 n.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, timeStamp: 120348.50000000006, jQuery112407953633868134593: true, …}
userCodeAppPanel:38 saveEventDescription: idS=05 , text=Seventh Time
userCodeAppPanel:21 n.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, timeStamp: 120348.50000000006, jQuery112407953633868134593: true, …}
userCodeAppPanel:38 saveEventDescription: idS=05 , text=Seventh Time
userCodeAppPanel:21 n.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, timeStamp: 120348.50000000006, jQuery112407953633868134593: true, …}
userCodeAppPanel:38 saveEventDescription: idS=05 , text=Seventh Time
userCodeAppPanel:21 n.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, timeStamp: 120348.50000000006, jQuery112407953633868134593: true, …}
userCodeAppPanel:38 saveEventDescription: idS=05 , text=Seventh Time
userCodeAppPanel:21 n.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, timeStamp: 120348.50000000006, jQuery112407953633868134593: true, …}
userCodeAppPanel:38 saveEventDescription: idS=05 , text=Seventh Time
userCodeAppPanel:21 n.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, timeStamp: 120348.50000000006, jQuery112407953633868134593: true, …}
userCodeAppPanel:38 saveEventDescription: idS=05 , text=Seventh Time
userCodeAppPanel:21 n.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, timeStamp: 120348.50000000006, jQuery112407953633868134593: true, …}
userCodeAppPanel:38 saveEventDescription: idS=05 , text=Seventh Time
1995166154-warden_bin_i18n_warden.js:56 Net state changed from IDLE to BUSY
7userCodeAppPanel:6 dispEvents()
1995166154-warden_bin_i18n_warden.js:56 Net state changed from BUSY to IDLE
*/
```

Then I did the same sort of thing with the Edt and Sav buttons.  I used the same functions as the dialog method used but instead of going to a dialog I put the text into a textarea on the top and edited it and then press the Sav button and after doing it several times I found that it worked perfectly.

I've reduced the code as much as I can.

code.gs

```
function dialogtestStartUp()
{
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Dialog Test') 
    .addItem('Test Dialog', 'showDialogTest')
    .addToUi();  
}
function setupStartUpTrigger(){
  if(!isTrigger('dialogtestStartUp')){
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('dialogtestStartUp').forSpreadsheet(gSSID).onOpen().create();
  }
}

function showDialogTest(){
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('dialogtest').setHeight(550).setWidth(400);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Dialog Test')
}


function saveMyEventDescription(evObj){
  Logger.log('saveMyEventDescription:\nevObj.text=%s\nevObj.calId=%s\nevObj.evId=%s\nevObj.idS=%s',evObj.text,evObj.calId,evObj.evId,evObj.idS);
  CalendarApp.getCalendarById(evObj.calId).getEventById(evObj.evId).setDescription(evObj.text);
  return true;
} 

function getEventDescription(evObj){
  evObj['text']=CalendarApp.getCalendarById(evObj.calId).getEventById(evObj.evId).getDescription();
  Logger.log('getEventDescription:\nevObj.text=%s\nevObj.calId=%s\nevObj.evId=%s\nevObj.idS=%s',evObj.text,evObj.calId,evObj.evId,evObj.idS);
  return evObj;
}

function getMyEvents(){//This is where the event descriptions and buttons are generated.  Then they're loaded into the html page when it loads.
  Logger.log('getMyEvents');
  var allCals=CalendarApp.getAllCalendars();
  var s=Utilities.formatString('<strong>%s</strong>',Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"E MMM d, yyyy HHmm"));
  var min=60 * 1000;
  var hr=60 * min;
  var day=24 * hr;
  var wk=7 * day;
  var start = new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0));
  var end=new Date(start.valueOf() + (5 * wk));
  var incl=['Daily Events'];
  for(var i=0;i<allCals.length;i++)
  {
    if(incl.indexOf(allCals[i].getName())>-1)
    {
      s+=Utilities.formatString('<br /><strong>%s</strong>',allCals[i].getName());
      var events=allCals[i].getEvents(start, end);
      if(events)
      {
        s+='<br /><ul>';
        for(j=0;j<events.length;j++)
        {
          var calId=allCals[i].getId();
          var evId=events[j].getId();
          var evDesc=events[j].getDescription();
          var idS=String(i)+String(j);
          if(events[j].isAllDayEvent())
          {
            s+=Utilities.formatString('<li><strong>%s</strong>-AllDay %s <input type="hidden" id="ids-%s" value="%s,%s" /> <input type="button" title="Move or Delete Event Dialog" name="MoveOrDeleteEvent" value="Remove" onClick="movdelDialog(\'ids-%s\',\'%s\',\'%s\');" /></li>',events[j].getTitle(),Utilities.formatDate(events[j].getStartTime(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"E MMM d"),idS,calId,evId,idS,calId,evId);
          }
          else
          {
            s+=Utilities.formatString('<li><strong>%s</strong>-%s <input type="hidden" id="ids-%s" value="%s,%s" /><input type="button" title="Move or Delete Event Dialog" name="MoveOrDeleteEvent" value="Remove" onClick="movdelDialog(\'%s\',\'%s\',\'%s\');" /></li>',events[j].getTitle(),Utilities.formatDate(events[j].getStartTime(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"E MMM d - HHmm"),idS,calId,evId,idS,calId,evId);
          }
          s+=Utilities.formatString('<br /><div id="evdesc-%s">%s</div>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="edtbtn-%s" type="button" value="Edit" title="Edit Dialog" onClick="editEventDescription(\'%s\',\'%s\',\'%s\',\'%s\');" /></li>',idS,evDesc,idS,calId,evId,idS,evDesc);
          s+=Utilities.formatString('<input type="button" id="edt-%s" value="Edt" onClick="edtEvntDesc(\'%s\',\'%s\',\'%s\',\'%s\');" />',idS,calId,evId,idS,evDesc);
          s+=Utilities.formatString('<input type="button" id="sav-%s" value="Sav" onClick="savEvntDesc(\'%s\',\'%s\',\'%s\',\'%s\');" />',idS,calId,evId,idS,evDesc);
        }
        s+='</ul>';
      }
    }
  }
  return s;
}

function delMyEvents(idA)
{
  if(idA)
  {
    for(var i=0;i<idA.length;i++)
    {
      var cal=CalendarApp.getCalendarById(idA[i][0]);//calendarId
      cal.getEventById(idA[i][1]).deleteEvent();//eventId
    }
  }
  return true;
}

function getTimeStamp()
{
  return Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "E MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a");
}
```

The html which I call dialogtest.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
      <script>
    $(function(){
      dispEvents();
    });
    function dispEvents(){
       console.log('dispEvents()');
      google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(upDateEvents)
        .getMyEvents();
    }
    function upDateEvents(hl){
      $('#hotbox').html(hl);
    }
    function openEventDescriptionEditDialog(evObj){
      console.log('openEventDescriptionEditDialog: idS=%s , text=%s',evObj.idS,evObj.text);    
      var alreadySent=false;
      $('#dialog-1').dialog({autopen:true,width:250,height:300});
      $('#dialog-1 #evdesc').val(evObj.text);
      $('#dialog-1 #saveBtn').button().click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e);
        evObj.text=$('#dialog-1 #evdesc').val();
        if(true){
          saveEventDescription(evObj);
          alreadySent=true;
        }
        //$(this).parent().dialog('close');
      });
      $('#dialog-1 #clsBtn').button().click(function(e){
        $(this).parent().dialog('close');
      });
    }
    function editEventDescription(calId,evId,idS,evDesc){
      var evObj={calId:calId,evId:evId,idS:idS,text:evDesc};
      openEventDescriptionEditDialog(evObj);
    }
    function saveEventDescription(evObj){
      console.log('saveEventDescription: idS=%s , text=%s',evObj.idS,evObj.text);
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(evObj){
        dispEvents();
        $('#dialog-1').dialog('close');
      })
      .saveMyEventDescription(evObj);
    }
    function edtEvntDesc(calId,evId,idS,evDesc){
      var evObj={calId:calId,evId:evId,idS:idS,text:evDesc};
      $('#ta1').val(evObj.text);
      console.log(evObj);
    }
    function savEvntDesc(calId,evId,idS,evDesc){
      var evObj={calId:calId,evId:evId,idS:idS,text:evDesc};
      evObj.text=$('#ta1').val();
      console.log(evObj);
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(Obj){
        dispEvents();
      })
      .saveMyEventDescription(evObj);
    }
    console.log("My code");
  </script>
  <style>
    #dialog-1{display:none;}
    input[type="button"]{background-color:#ffffff;border:1px solid #000;-webkit-appearance:none;}
    #dialogs input[type="button"]{margin:10px 0;}
    #ta1{direction:ltr;}
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="container">
  <div id="div1"><textarea id="ta1" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea></div>
   <div id="hotbox"></div>
   </div>
   <input type="button" value="Display Events" onClick="dispEvents();" />
   <div id="dialogs">
   <div id="dialog-1" title="Edit Event Description">
     <textarea id="evdesc" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
     <input type="button" value="Save Edits" id="saveBtn" title="Save Edits" /><br />
     <input type="button" value="Close" id="clsBtn" title="Close Dialog" />     
   </div>
   <input type="button" value="Close" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

In an attempt to fix the problem without actually understanding what's causing it I added the following to the dialog:

```
function openEventDescriptionEditDialog(evObj){
      console.log('openEventDescriptionEditDialog: idS=%s , text=%s',evObj.idS,evObj.text);    
      var alreadySent=false;//Added this to mitigate the problem
      $('#dialog-1').dialog({autopen:true,width:250,height:300});
      $('#dialog-1 #evdesc').val(evObj.text);
      $('#dialog-1 #saveBtn').button().click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e);//you will still see these on the console but only one saveEventDescription
        evObj.text=$('#dialog-1 #evdesc').val();
        if(!alreadySent){//Keeps the additional events from occuring
          saveEventDescription(evObj);
          alreadySent=true;
        }
        //$(this).parent().dialog('close');
      });
      $('#dialog-1 #clsBtn').button().click(function(e){
        $(this).parent().dialog('close');
      });
    }
```

So my question is: does one really have to debounce dialog switches?

Comment: Somewhere in your code you are adding new event listeners to same elements to get those symptoms. Try using `off()` before adding new listener

Comment: I guess it's because I'm executing this `$('#dialog-1').dialog({autopen:true,width:250,height:300});` everytime I click the edit button.  Thanks for comment.

Comment: I think it's the other buttons causing problem isn't it? Doing `$('#dialog-1 #clsBtn').button().click..` more than once will add a new listener each time on top of previous listener(s)

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that multiple times. Initialize the widget once. When you want to open the dialog, use `$('#dialog-1').dialog("open");`

Comment: I was just thinking about using the open instead.  Thanks for that suggestion

Comment: Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I had the similar issue, which was eventually solved by registering absolutely all event listeners in the startup function that loads the master page. The idea is that when you navigate away from the master page, the page doesn't get refreshed. Instead, it clears the container div element and then adds new DOM elements to the container. The new widgets are returned as a string by the HtmlService. Basically, it comes down to the single master page loading other partial views. In this case, you will never have to add event listeners more than once.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author to move it to the answer space)*.

After receiving your helpful suggestions I made most of the changes to the html file as shown below.  The big thing was not to keep running the initialization command repeatedly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
      <script>
    var gEvObj={};
    $(function(){
      dispEvents();
      $('#dialog-1').dialog({autoOpen: false, width: 250, height: 300, resizable: true, draggable: true});
      $('#dialog-1 #saveBtn').button().click(function(e){
        saveEventDescription();
      });
      $('#dialog-1 #clsBtn').button().click(function(e){
        $(this).parent().dialog('close');
      });
    });
    function dispEvents(){
       console.log('dispEvents()');
      google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(upDateEvents)
        .getMyEvents();
    }
    function upDateEvents(hl){
      $('#hotbox').html(hl);
    }
    function editEventDescription(calId,evId,idS,evDesc){
      gEvObj={calId:calId,evId:evId,idS:idS,text:evDesc};
      $('#dialog-1 #evdesc').val(gEvObj.text);
      $('#dialog-1').dialog("open");
    }
    function saveEventDescription(){
      gEvObj.text=$('#dialog-1 #evdesc').val();
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(){
        dispEvents();
        $('#dialog-1').dialog('close');
      })
      .saveMyEventDescription(gEvObj);
    }
    console.log("My code");
  </script>
  <style>
    #dialog-1{display:none;}
    input[type="button"]{background-color:#ffffff;border:1px solid #000;-webkit-appearance:none;}
    #dialogs input[type="button"]{margin:10px 0;}
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div id="hotbox"></div>
   </div>
   <input type="button" value="Display Events" onClick="dispEvents();" />
   <div id="dialogs">
   <div id="dialog-1" title="Edit Event Description">
     <textarea id="evdesc" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
     <input type="button" value="Save" id="saveBtn" title="Save Edits" /><br />
     <input type="button" value="Close" id="clsBtn" title="Close Dialog" />     
   </div>
   <input type="button" value="Close" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Then I went into the other program and did the same sort of thing and now it's running very smoothly as well.